# Post messages to model dialog

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm planning to create modeless dialog and to receive messages from another thread. According to my understanding to creating modeless dialog I need to create CWinThread and some frame or dialog inside of CWinThread derived class object. But do I really need to create frame/dialog? Why I can't post messages direct to CWinThread derived class object?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a dialog to receive messages, but you do need a window handle. That window handle does not need to be associated with something visual. What I think you need is a message only window.

In MFC you can do this with `CWnd` using the `CreateEx` method to create the message only window. Pass `HWND_MESSAGE` to the `hWndParent` parameter of `CreateEx`.

It is true that you can create a hidden modeless dialog just to receive messages. However, this is grossly wasteful. What's more, MFC is designed around the concept that dialogs are created in the main UI thread. So for a number of different reasons you really do want to avoid creating a dialog just to receive messages in a thread. Use a message only window.

Comment: Please, correct me if I'm wrong. Firstly I need To Create class derived from CWnd object in main  or in created with CWinThread thread. Then I can just send message from my secondary thread.

Comment: Yes, I would derive a class from `CWnd`. And call `CreateEx` in its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The message handler posts/sends messages to Window handlers, so you need a placeholder window to receive that message and handle as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** post messages to a CWinThread derived object using PostThreadMessage. But there are some cases where this is dangerous, discussed here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/225755/PostThreadMessage-Demystified