# Get modeless dialog window handler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm creating **modeless** dialog that will be used to receive win messages.

```
AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(modHolder));
```

How to get `HWND` of modeless dialog window?

Comment: What about your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987991/post-messages-to-model-dialog)? I told you that you do not need to make a dialog just to receive messages. Why do you ask questions and then ignore answers?

Comment: I have already created modeless dialog and would like to test both versions - modeless an message only window. Just for education reason

Answer (score 1):

How do you create the modeless dialog ?

something like this?:

```
CYourDialog pDialog = new CYourDialog;
pDialog->Create(...);
```

then you could do :

```
HWND hWnd = pDialog->GetSafeHwnd();
```

Comment: Ok, now I have hWnd and how to pass it to main thread that has called AfxBeginThread?

Comment: You can Post or Send a message to the main application thread with the HWND as a paremeter

Comment: yes, but how to tell modHolder what is HWND of main application? I will need it to post messages

Answer (score 0):

The HWND of any MFC window is m_hWnd of the CWnd-derived class. But there is no window in the line of code you posted.